# How to export Apache Velocity Engine as .jar using NetBeans?

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, velocity, templating-engine

We have made some edits on [Apache Velocity Engine](https://github.com/MohammedFuad97/velocity-engine/tree/1.7.x), and now I need to export it as a .jar to use it into our projects.

How can I build it on NetBeans without selecting a Main Class cause there is no Main Class in the Engine, or I just did not find?

I found solutions like project > properties > build > packaging, but I don't even have [packaging option] in my build list, there is only compile option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create jar using `maven install`, see [velocity build](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/build.html).